# Finding the stationary distribution of a markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am asked to compute the stationary distribution of the markov chain with state space $E=\mathbb{N}_0$, $q_n >0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and transition matrix below:

\begin{bmatrix} 
 q_0 & q_1&q_2&q_3 &q_4&q_5&\dots             \\
 1     &  0 &  \\
      & 1     &  0 &      &          \\
      &      &  1 &   0   &          \\
    &      &   &    1  & 0 &   \\
    &      &   &      & 1 &  0 \\
    &      &   &      &  &  \ddots &\ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}

I used $\pi P = \pi$ and I also tried the way from my other thread [Calculating stationary distribution of markov chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140436/calculating-stationary-distribution-of-markov-chain). Letting $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k \pi_k$ What I got was:

$\pi_0 = \pi_1 +q_0\pi_0 \\ \pi_1 = \pi_2 +q_1\pi_0 \\ \pi_2 = \pi_3 +q_2\pi_0 \\ \pi_k =\pi_{k+1}+q_k\pi_0 \\ x^k\pi_k =x^k\pi_{k+1}+x^kq_k\pi_0 \\ \sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k\pi_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{k-1}\pi_{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^kq_k\pi_0 \\ g(x) =x^{-1}g(x)+\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^kq_k\pi_0$

and also

$\pi_0=\frac{1}{1-q_0}\pi_1 \\ \pi_1 =\pi_0(1-q_0) \\ \pi_2 =\pi_0(1-q_0-q_1) \\ \pi_3 =\pi_0(1-q_0-q_1-q_2) \\\pi_n = \pi_0(1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q_k) \\$

I tried fiddling with it here and there but I cant seem to get anywhere to finish this problem. i.e. I can't seem to find $\pi_k$ for all $k \in E=\{0,\dots,n\}$. How would I finish this problem?

Edit: $\pi_n = \pi_0(1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q_k) \\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\pi_n =1 \\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\pi_0(1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q_k) =1 \\ \pi_0 = \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q_k)} = \frac{1}{(1-q_0)+(1-q_o-q_1)+(1-q_0-q_1-q_2)+\dots}$

Looking at @BrianMScott 's comment, how do I get the bottom line to simplify to $\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)q_k$? /To simplify the last line above?

Comment: You're almost there, you just have to find $\pi_0$.  And there's one fact you haven't used yet: you want $\pi$ to be a probability distribution, so you need $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \pi_k = 1$...

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge , I've used your hint and continued on, could you possibly take a look?

Comment: Since $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q_k = 1$, we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q_k) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty q_k$.  Now try interchanging the order of summation.

Comment: Note that your written-out denominator starts at $n=1$; it should start at $n=0$ with a term $1$; this is where the $+1$ in Brian's $k+1$ comes from.

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge , I understood what you did and I got the correct answer.

@ joriki Thanks for pointing it out, I did I start with $n=0$, but since it turns out to be $(1-1) =0$, I did not write it out in my workings above.

Comment: @Richard: Where does the $-1$ come from? As I wrote above, the $n=0$ term is $1$; the sum over $q_k$ from $k=0$ to $-1$ is $0$. By the way, pinging doesn't work if you leave a space between the @ and the user name; I read this comment by chance.

Comment: @joriki Sorry, I got mixed up with sums and products (empty products are $1$). May I ask, did you have 'another' way to get $\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)q_k$? Now the denominator reads $1+(1-q_0)+(1-q_o-q_1)+(1-q_0-q_1-q_2)+\dots$, is there another way to get to $\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)q_k$ apart from using Nate's method in the above comment?

Comment: @Richard: No, that's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've made some errors in transferring stuff from the other question. The other question has a finite state space up to $n$, whereas your state space is infinite and $n$ in the problem statement is just a generic index, not a limit. Accordingly, the upper limits in the line with the three summation signs should be $\infty$, not $n$. Also you'd need to explain why you can lower $k$ by $1$ in the middle term; I don't think you can. This also looks like an incorrect transfer from the other question, as does your switch to $k$ as a generic index and $n$ as the upper limit of the state space in the last line.

The equations in the second block (after "and also") look OK (including the last one, where you correctly used $n$ as a generic index). As Nate wrote in a comment, you can determine $\pi_0$ by requiring that the $\pi_n$ sum up to $1$ (again summing up to $\infty$). Note that the sum of the factors on the right-hand side need not converge; although the factors go to $0$ because the sum over the $q_k$ is $1$, they could go to $0$ e.g. as $1/n$, yielding the harmonic series; in that case there would be no stationary distribution.

Comment: Specifically, if I've made no computational error, one needs $\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)q_k$ to converge.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianM.Scott and joriki, I took out some paper and did some further calculations and posted what I got in my original post above, but how did you get the terms to simplify to $\sum_{k\ge 0}(k+1)q_k$?

Comment: @Sasha , could you possibly take a look at what I've done? I tried calculating the stationary distribution using 2 ways, one using your method. Maybe I've done something wrong..

Comment: @Richard: I don't know whether you can ping someone like that who has never interacted with this post. In case you don't get a response from Sasha, you may have to comment under his post instead.

Comment: @joriki Okay, thanks for your pointer! I didnt realise that. Will wait a while and see how it goes.